# Combining the variables into 1 variable

Tags: python

I have used countries as an example but I was wondering if I needed to combine the countries into one variable or do I need to do something else?

```
import random

afghanistan = 189
albania = 189
algeria = 189
andorra = 189

if albania == afghanistan or albania or algeria or andorra:
    albania = random.randint(1, 196)



print(afghanistan)
print(albania)
print(algeria)
print(andorra)
```

Comment: It is not clear what is your goal? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Agreed, we don't know what you want to do. Also, that `if` might not be doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here about your goals, but your condition doesn't check `albania` against the other values right now.
It checks if `albania` equals `afghanistan`, or if `albania`, `algeria`, or `andorra` are not 0.

You should create a separate condition for each:

```
import random

afghanistan = 189
albania = 189
algeria = 189
andorra = 189

if albania == afghanistan or albania == algeria or albania == andorra:
    albania = random.randint(1, 196)



print(afghanistan)
print(albania)
print(algeria)
print(andorra)
```

Comment: Obviously we don't know what OP thinks. To me it's neither clear what combining countries into one means nor how the OP thinks the `if` works. It would be more sane to wait till OP clarifies.

Comment: I understand, but based on the OPs question about combining variables, and the unusual `if`, I've posted this answer hoping it might be useful. I'll edit or remove it if it turns out this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve, but I think the only reasonable objective is to find ids for the countries in a randomized way, which you could achieve like this:

```
import random

afghanistan = 189
albania = 189
algeria = 189
andorra = 189

countries = [afghanistan, albania, algeria, andorra]

for index, country in enumerate(countries):
    while country in (countries[:index] + countries[index+1:]):
        country = random.randint(1, 196)
        countries[index] = country

print(countries) #example output (will be different each time): [170, 32, 14, 189]
```